# UIButton's click(IBAction) not getting triggered programatically

Tags: ios, uibutton, ibaction

I have a simple UIButton in a viewController.

```
- (IBAction)btnEnter:(id)sender {
   ..
   ..
}
```

Now I want to trigger the button press action programatically one of library functions (didFinishPickingmediaWithInfo) gets executed

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{

// Do Something

txtBoxAboveEnterButton = @"Data populated successfully";

[self btnEnter:nil];

[reader dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}
```

The function is getting called and the text box above Enter button is getting populated with the dummy text but click is not getting triggered. Please help me out!

Comment: you don't have a btnEnter method, you have a btnEnter:(id)sender method.  Try passing a parameter (nil or self) to that method.

Comment: tried [self btnEnter:self] and also [self btnEnter:nil], doesnt work :(!

Comment: Are you certain that myfuntion [sic] is being called?

Comment: So IBAction is called and the problem is that in user interface you don't see how the button is selected and deselected?

Comment: is the IBAction is called but don't execute the action internal code ? I mean did you try to put to check if the IBAction is ever called ?

Comment: The button works when clicked manually so I guess IBAction in itself works via system call but not when I programatically call it from another function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are calling is btnEnter with no parameter.  It doesn't look like you have that defined.  Try passing a paramter like `nil` or `self` to it:

```
[self btnEnter:nil];
```

Comment: Your updated question has btnEnterISBN: being called but you are interested in btnEnter:

Comment: sorry for the typo. The button is btnEnter only. [self btnEnter:nil] doesnt work for - (IBAction) btnEnter:(id) sender{}